# Storing a value in array during a for loop

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

So I have a piece of code below that is used to make a density plot and make the plot into grids, where I then find the center of each grid and store it in the varible called cp. The code for this is bellow.

```
dp = DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + 
         y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Minimal", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
ClearAll[centers2]
centers2[region_ : Disk[{0, 0}, 1]][{nc_, nr_}, {xrange_, yrange_}] :=
  Select[RegionMember[region]]@centers[{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]
{xrange, yrange} = {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}};

{nc, nr} = {10, 10};


Show[dp, Graphics[{White, PointSize[Medium], Circle[], 
   Point@centers2[][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]}]]
means[n_] := MovingAverage[Subdivide[##, n] & @@ #, 2]; &;





cp = centers2[][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}];
```

Now what I wanted to do was try and use the variable cp in for loop. This loop look at each data point in cp and then perform certain calculations. First it would extract the data point, then separate it into x and y point. Next it would be used to find a value of S1 and S2. After this is done I would like the value of S1 and S2 to be stored in a new array.

**My attempt**

The whole code I have used is pasted bellow

```
dp = DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + 
         y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Minimal", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
ClearAll[centers2]
centers2[region_ : Disk[{0, 0}, 1]][{nc_, nr_}, {xrange_, yrange_}] :=
  Select[RegionMember[region]]@centers[{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]
{xrange, yrange} = {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}};

{nc, nr} = {10, 10};


Show[dp, Graphics[{White, PointSize[Medium], Circle[], 
   Point@centers2[][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]}]]
means[n_] := MovingAverage[Subdivide[##, n] & @@ #, 2]; &;





cp = centers2[][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}];

For[i = 0; e = Length[cp], i < e, i++, point = Part[cp, i];
 x = Part[point, 1]; y = Part[point, 2]; 
 S1 = (E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2 - ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[
       2 Pi])^2; 
 S2 = 2 E^-((x^2 + y^2)^2) ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])]
```

Currently I am stuck as for some reason I receive an error when trying to get the value of x and y therefore S1 and S2 is not calculated. I also have not found a way that I can use to try and store the S1 and S2 values I calculate.

Thank you for all your help and understanding

Comment: Use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) instead of `For`, then you'll get the array generated automatically (generally, *never* use `For` in Mathematica, if you need something like it, use [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html)). Here's a start: `{S1,S2}=Transpose[Apply[Function[{x,y},{…}],{1}]]`

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks for your comment. I have looked at the 3 alternatives to for that you have provided, which one would you suggest I use in this case? At this point I think Map might be better but with my limited knowledge I could be wrong.

Best of Thanks

Comment: Yes, `Map` would be a good option. I think however that `Apply` might be slightly better in this case: With `Map`, you would get each point as single argument, so you would have to do `Map[Function[point,x=point[[1]];…],cp]` to get `x` and `y`. You could of course define a function as `f[{x_,y_}]:=…` (note the `{…}` on the left side) and do `Map[f,cp]`. `Apply` (at level 1) is slightly cleaner, since you can do `Apply[Function[{x,y},…],cp,{1}]` (so you get `x` and `y` separately), or `f[x_,y_]:=…` (note the lack of `{…}`) and then `Apply[f,cp,{1}]`. See also the example in my other comment.

Comment: @LukasLang would it be possible for you to give me a small starting point on using the apply function for my case? It seems like all of my attempts do not work out very well 

Thanks for your time